# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized

Tags: servlets, illegalstateexception, servletconfig

I am trying to create an UI component that allow the user to customize the timeout of sessions. So I created a servlet as below:

```
public class SessionTimeoutServlet extends AbstractBaseServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2567293974465204729L;

    public static final String REQUEST_TIMEOUT_PARAMETR_NAME = "timeout";
    private static final String TIMEOUT_TYPE_INIT_PARAMETER_NAME = "timeoutType";
    private static final String WEB_TYPE_TIMEOUT = "web";
    private static final String WEBSERVICE_TYPE_TIMEOUT = "webService";

    @EJB(mappedName = SessionSettingsRemote.BEAN_NAME)
    private SessionSettingsRemote sessionSettingsBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initTimeout() {
        try {
            String timeoutType = getServletContext().getInitParameter(TIMEOUT_TYPE_INIT_PARAMETER_NAME);
            if (WEBSERVICE_TYPE_TIMEOUT.equals(timeoutType)) {
                setCustomTimeout(sessionSettingsBean.getSessionSettingsDTO().getWebServiceSessionTimeoutInterval());
            } else if (WEB_TYPE_TIMEOUT.equals(timeoutType)) {
                setCustomTimeout(sessionSettingsBean.getSessionSettingsDTO().getWebSessionTimeoutInterval());
            } else {
                setCustomTimeout(30);
            }
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            setCustomTimeout(30);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int timeout = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(REQUEST_TIMEOUT_PARAMETR_NAME));
        setCustomTimeout(timeout);
    }

    public static void setCustomTimeout(int customTimeout) {
        SessionManagerListener.setCustomTimeout(customTimeout);
    }

}
```

However, when I deploy this on GlassFish, I get below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:199)
    at com.accedian.ems.uiapplication.server.servlets.SessionTimeoutServlet.initTimeout(SessionTimeoutServlet.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl$3.run(InjectionManagerImpl.java:766)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.invokeLifecycleMethod(InjectionManagerImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:531)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5732)
```

I have used `getServletConfig()` before `getServletContext()` but it was `null`. So why is my config and context are not properly set ?

Comment: Don't use an `@PostConstruct` override the `init` method instead. This will be called too early in the lifecycle (after construction but before the container had any change of calling the `init(ServletConfig)` hence everything is still `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Servlets predate managed beans and annotations and all the fancy stuff you see since Java EE 6. Previously, you have to explicitly implement a predefined abstract/template method in order to perform a task at a certain moment in the lifecycle.

For servlets, in order to hook on its initialization the same way you'd use `@PostConstruct` on a "normal" managed bean, you have to override the predefined [`GenericServlet#init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init--) method.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

The `getServletContext()` will be available there.

If you pay attention to the [`GenericServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) javadoc, you'll notice that there's also an `init(ServletConfig)`. It's however strongly recommended to **not** use that method, but use `init()` instead. The default implementation of `init(ServletConfig)` namely takes care that the `ServletContext` is properly set. You'd have to mind calling `super.init(config)` to not make the same mistake. As a historical note, see that the canonical name of a `@PostConstruct` method as you see on managed beans, "init", is inherited from exactly this Servlet API.

In case you wonders, the `@PreDestroy` equivalent is the [`GenericServlet#destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#destroy--) method.

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
    // ...
}
```